# Markdown link escaping layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have a website I am making with Bootstrap and Jekyll. I recently ran into a problem where, on blog posts, if an author's name is hyperlinked (to a Google+ profile, for example), a snippet of html is displayed above the body as if the HTML syntax is broken.

The blog post is written in markdown, and the layout is a separate HTML file. Here is [the code in question, including the layout code](https://gist.github.com/irowebbn/02f524ffae23fb847aac), but basically the file is like this:

```
---
layout: post
(some other front matter metadata)
---

by [author](link)
```

Authors names who are not linked do not have this problem, and the problem does not occur on the blog feed page. Also, if I place some text in the line above the by-line, the snippet goes away. How can I get rid of this bug? It seems like there is an error in my markdown.

Edit: If it helps any, my markdown highlighter in the config.yml is pygments

Comment: What is the HTML generated by Markdown? Can you point us to the page in question, or at least use "view Source" in your browser and copy/paste the HTML into your post?

Comment: @Waylan I just added it to the Gist. Looks like the problem might be in a `meta` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stemming from line 16 to 18 of your gist that contains the html output, this is where it's from:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>by <a href="https://plus.google.com/+NickSuch/">Nick Such</a></p>

" >
```

This means that the erroneous output generated is not from your post layout or the markdown, but the way that the provided `head` include in the theme is parsing the data. You'll have to trace this back to the header used in the `page` layout as the post layout is using it. Chances are the when you add some text above the 'by' line the HTML generated is closed properly and the problem is 'hidden' after that.

Referring to the comments, here is a summary of the problem and the solution:

The main issue was that the post contained markdown that would be parsed into HTML tags which is then put into the `og:description` `meta property`.

Here was the original template code in the `header` include for the theme's layout.

`<meta property="og:description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}" >`

**The solution to this is** to strip out all the HTML before putting it into the `meta property` as HTML code is not allowed inside the meta properties `content`. This can be done with the `strip_html` Liquid code, as mentioned by @[Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696044/erik-gillespie). [Read the documentation here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#strip_html)

```
<meta property="og:description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html }}{% else %}{{ site.description | strip_html }}{% endif %}" />
```

(HTML tags should also be closed with the `/` if they are one-liners for proper closing of tags)

Comment: Here is the theme code: https://github.com/ainc/awesomeincu-2015/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/page.html It looks like the tag is set to be `<meta property="og:description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}" >` So it's taking the first para of the post (in this case the by line) and using it as the excerpt, but somehow that breaks the tag

Comment: Perhaps the page excerpt or site description has a quote symbol or HTML in it?

Comment: Don't think meta description can contain HTML. so a workaround would be to use a page.excerpt that does not have parsed html, or add a YAML variable that contains a brief description of the post, and then do {{ page.brief }} instead of {{ page.excerpt }}

Comment: I think Liquid has a filter that can trim/escape that stuff too.

Comment: @erikgillespie no excerpt is set for the post, but it looks like it is taking the byline as the excerpt, which is a markdown hyperlink. Site description does not have a quote

Comment: Try filtering the content through `strip_html`: https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#strip_html

Comment: @matrixanomaly Do you think there's a way to fix this for all the posts without editing each one individually?

Comment: Oh sweet, @ErikGillespie did not know that existed! in that case @irowe you could just drop in `| strip_html` into both `page.excerpt` and `site.description` like `{{ site.description | strip_html }}` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @erikgillespie that worked! I changed the meta tag to `<meta property="og:description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}" >` and now there is no html in the tag

Comment: also, you should add the close `/` after those meta properties, that might prevent incorrect closing of the tags. Which you've done in some parts of the theme --> `/>` but not others. @ErikGillespie you should post an answer on this too regarding strip html :).

Comment: @matrixanomaly Do you mind summing up some of this in your answer so future stumbler-upons don't have to sift through this conversation?

Comment: yep for sure. i thought you might want to post an answer so it could be accepted as the answer.

Comment: @erikgillespie I added an answer summing it up with a reference to your help. I can't accept my own answer on the same day I post it ,though

Comment: Eh, you really got to the bottom of it. I just had a nice little nugget of useful trivia.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Erikgillespie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667868/markdown-link-escaping-layout/30669122#comment49400785_30669122), I figured it out.

Looks like the problem was in the page layout where there was a `meta` tag that looked like this: `<meta property="og:description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}" >`

It was taking the first paragraph (in this case the by line with the link) as the excerpt, which was generated as HTML and placed in the `meta` tag. Since the tag can't contain HTML, it broke the tag.

The solution was to place `strip_html` liquid tag in the `meta` so it passed plain text, not html: `<meta property="og:description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}" >` Putting this in the `_layouts/page.html` solved it.